# How to integrate database with hudson?

Tags: database, selenium-webdriver, automation, hudson, build-automation

I want to integrate database with hudson for running my webdriver scripts

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way as below

1 - Install DB server on your Hudson machine

2 - Create a job "Restore DB" to restore your "Needed DB" on Hudson machine.

3 - Create a job "WebDriver Test" to run your scripts

4 - Create a job "Delete DB" to delete your "Needed DB"

5 - Config job "Restore DB" to trigger "WebDriver Test" when it completes

6 - Config job "WebDriver Test" to trigger "Delete DB" when it completes

Comment: If you dont want to host your DB on Hudson machine, please make sure to get authentication between machines OK. Because you may need to provide OS authentication/DB authentication to restore/delete/connect to DB